# Query for highest x in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 models

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vote_count = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Watchlist(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    movie_id = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __int__(self):
        return self.userid
```

what will be query to fetch highest watched movie

Answer (score 1):

from django.db.models import Count

```
# the most watched Movie instance
the_most_watched_movie = Movie.objects.annotate(count=Count('watchlist')).order_by('-count').first()
```

Also it could be done via `Watchlist` if you would need it for some reason

```
watchlist = Watchlist.objects.annotate(count=Count('userid')).values('movie_id', 'count').order_by('-count').first()

movie_id = watchlist['movie_id']  # the most watched movie id
# the most watched Movie instance
the_most_watched_movie = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)
```